# Unable to access value of req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, request, axios

I am trying to do a PUT request to update my DB in Mongo using Axios so I can update the current week and season. In my route, I can access the req.body, but if I try to set the values, it says the values are undefined. I have tried many different things at this point. I ran into this issue as well: "Cast to Number failed".

Here is what the request looks like:

```
function currentWeek() {
  const currentWeek =
    "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nfl/scores/json/CurrentWeek?key=...";

    axios.get(currentWeek).then((res) => {
      const weekCheck = res.data;
      const timeframeURL =
      "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nfl/scores/json/Timeframes/current?key=...";
      console.log(weekCheck);
    axios.get(timeframeURL).then((res) => {
      const timeframeWeek = res.data;
      // console.log(timeframeWeek);
      const thisWeek = timeframeWeek.filter(
        (timeframeWeek) => timeframeWeek.Week === weekCheck
      );
      console.log(thisWeek);
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        };
  
        axios
          .put("http://localhost:4000/api/currentweek/5ffce18e78d4742414cf279e", thisWeek, config)
          .then((res) => console.log("working"))
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
        console.log("Done!");
      });
    }); 
}
```

Here is my route:

```
router.put("/:_id", async (req, res) => {
  const { Season, Week } = req.body;
  const { _id } = req.params;

  const weekField = {};

  // SETING THE VALUES FROM REQ.BODY TO BE IN weekField
  if (Season) weekField.Season = Season;
  if (Week) weekField.Week = Week;

  try {
    let weekParam = await CurrentWeek.find({_id});
    if (!weekParam) return res.stats(404).json({ msg: "ID in the Params does not exist" });
    console.log(_id);
    console.log(req.body) // RETURNS THE OBJECT CORRECTLY
    console.log(weekField); // RETURNS AS AN EMPTY OBJECT
    console.log("From Route ^^");
    weekParam = await CurrentWeek.findOneAndUpdate(
      _id,
      { $set: weekField },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.json(weekParam);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

Here is the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CurrentWeekSchema = mongoose.Schema([{
    Week: Number,
    Season: Number
}]);

const CurrentWeek = module.exports = mongoose.model('currentweek', CurrentWeekSchema); 
//^enables require from routes
module.exports.getCurrentWeek = function(callback, limit){
    CurrentWeek.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

And here is an example of the object I am trying to take in:

```
 [
  {
    SeasonType: 3,
    Season: 2020,
    Week: 2,
    Name: 'Divisional Playoffs',
    ShortName: 'Divisional',
    StartDate: '2021-01-12T00:00:00',
    EndDate: '2021-01-18T23:59:59',
    FirstGameStart: '2021-01-16T16:35:00',
    FirstGameEnd: '2021-01-16T20:35:00',
    LastGameEnd: '2021-01-17T22:40:00',
    HasGames: true,
    HasStarted: true,
    HasEnded: false,
    HasFirstGameStarted: false,
    HasFirstGameEnded: false,
    HasLastGameEnded: false,
    ApiSeason: '2020POST',
   ApiWeek: '2'
  }
 ]
```

Comment: In your route you are trying to set the values?

Comment: I have one object in the 'currentweeks' collection in Mongo. I just want to update the week and season values with the PUT request.

Comment: befor sent put request do this, thisWeek = JSON.stringify(thisWeek), and tell me your result

Comment: It should set the values in `weekField`. Are you sure you are getting the values in the `req.body`?

Comment: @HamzaAnis thats what I thought too because I am doing this same exact thing with another set of data no problem. But for some reason weekField is returning as an empty object.

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi when I do thisWeek = JSON.stringify(thisWeek), it returned the following error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.". I tried doing this instead: const thisWeek = JSON.stringify(timeframeWeek.filter(
        (timeframeWeek) => timeframeWeek.Week === weekCheck
      )); and that turned that just converted the object to string data.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue and maybe this will be helpful for someone else in the future!

In my router file I need to change this:

```
  const { Season, Week } = req.body;
  const { _id } = req.params;

  const weekField = {};

  // SETING THE VALUES FROM REQ.BODY TO BE IN weekField
  if (Season) weekField.Season = Season;
  if (Week) weekField.Week = Week;
```

To this:

```
  const data = req.body;
  const { Season, Week } = data[0];
  const { _id } = req.params;

  const weekField = {};

  // SETING THE VALUES FROM REQ.BODY TO BE IN weekField
  if (Season) weekField.Season = Season;
  if (Week) weekField.Week = Week;
```

The reason is because the data that the put request is receiving is coming in an array, so I had to set the req.body to the first object in the array.